# Is it possible to dipatsch on useSelector function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Langage used : JS with REACT REDUX

The context : I have a component who render a list of quotes following the user filter and categories choice.

In my filter component, i store the select value (buttonsData), and here i re render a certains component depending on select value.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap'; 
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
//here each component following the user choice
import { AllForms } from './categories/AllForms';
import { AtoZ } from './sorted/AtoZ';
import { ZtoA } from './sorted/ZtoA';
import { Ascend } from './sorted/Ascend';
import CurrentOffers from './categories/CurrentOffers';
import ValidateOffers from './categories/ValidateOffers';

export const OfferList = () => {
  const buttonsData = useSelector((state) => state.buttonReducer);
 
  return (
    <Table hover responsive="md" className="folder__table">
      <thead className="folder__content">
        <tr className="folder__titles">
          <th className="folder__title"> </th>
          <th className="folder__title">Order REF</th>
          <th
            className="folder__title" 
          >
            Entité
          </th>
          <th className="folder__title">Customer</th>
          <th className="folder__title">Status</th>
          <th className="folder__title">Date</th>
          <th className="folder__title "> </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {buttonsData.activeComponent === 'AllForms' && <AllForms />}
       {buttonsData.activeComponent === 'Ascend' && <Ascend />}
       {buttonsData.activeComponent === 'validate' && <ValidateOffers />}
    </Table>
  );
};
```

I have used createSelector to filter and sort my datas (working fine).

```
import {  useSelector } from 'react-redux';


 export const SelectOffersValidate = () => {
 //here i select ALL my forms, get with axios
  const formsDatas = useSelector((state) => state.offersReducer);
  const sortedForms = [...formsDatas].filter(
    (oneOffer) => oneOffer.status == 'validate'
  );
  console.log(sortedForms);
   return sortedForms;
};


export const SelectOffersAscend = () => {
   const formsDatas = useSelector((state) => state.offersReducer);

  const sortedForms = [...formsDatas].sort((a, b) =>
    b.createdAt.localeCompare(a.createdAt)
  );
  return sortedForms;
};
```

Here a component filtered ( i have one component for AllForms, one for Validate and one for ascend, exaclty the same but with own select function)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { FiEdit3 } from 'react-icons/fi';
import {
   SelectOffersAscend,
} from '../../../selector/projects.selector.js';
import { isEmpty } from '../../../middlewares/verification.js';
import Moment from 'react-moment';

export const Ascend = () => { 


  const formsAscend = SelectOffersAscend();

 
  return (
    <>
       
      <tbody>
        {!isEmpty(formsAscend[0]) &&
          formsAscend?.map((oneForm) => {
            return (
              <tr key={oneForm.id}>
                <td>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
       
                  />
                </td>
                <td>{oneForm.ref} </td>
                <td> {oneForm.entity}</td>
                <td>{oneForm.customer} </td>

                <td>{oneForm.status} </td>
                <td>
                  <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY" date={oneForm.createdAt} />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <FiEdit3 />
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
      </tbody>
    </>
  );
};
```

My first problem :

I have made a component for EACH filter, but it's repetitive, is there a better way to do ?

The second problem :

"AllForms" and "ValidateOffers" are categories and "Ascend" is a filter.
For the moment i filter only with AllForms but i would like to filtered based on categories choosen.
I've tried to create an action to store the actual categories, so i've tried to dispatch on my createSelector validate function but it's looping so i don't think is the best way to do

SOLUTION : thanks to Chris whol helped me :)

So i have delete all my filtered component to just have one and create a custom hook

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import { OfferRows } from './OfferRows';

export const useFilteredOffers = () => {
  const buttonsData = useSelector((state) => state.buttonReducer);
  const offersData = useSelector((state) => state.offersReducer);

  return useMemo(() => {
    switch (buttonsData.activeComponent) {
      case 'Ascend': // fix casing
        return offersData?.sort((a, b) =>
          b.createdAt.localeCompare(a.createdAt)
        );
      case 'validate':
        return offersData?.filter((oneOffer) => oneOffer.status === 'validate');
      case 'not validate':
        return offersData?.filter(
          (oneOffer) => oneOffer.status === 'not validate'
        );
      case 'AtoZ':
        return offersData?.sort((a, b) => a.customer.localeCompare(b.customer));
      case 'ZtoA':
        return offersData?.sort((a, b) => b.customer.localeCompare(a.customer));

      default:
        return offersData;
    }
  }, [buttonsData.activeComponent, offersData]);
};

export const OfferList = () => {
  const filteredOffers = useFilteredOffers();

  return (
    <Table hover responsive="md" className="folder__table">
      <thead className="folder__content">
        <tr className="folder__titles">
          <th className="folder__title"> </th>
          <th className="folder__title">Order REF</th>
          <th className="folder__title">Entité</th>
          <th className="folder__title">Customer</th>
          <th className="folder__title">Status</th>
          <th className="folder__title">Date</th>
          <th className="folder__title "> </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <OfferRows offers={filteredOffers} />
    </Table>
  );
};
```

Here the rows

```
import React from 'react';
import { FiEdit3 } from 'react-icons/fi';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import { isEmpty } from '../../middlewares/verification.js';

export const OfferRows = ({ offers }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <tbody>
        {!isEmpty(offers[0]) &&
          offers?.map((oneForm) => {
            return (
              <tr key={oneForm.id}>
                <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" />
                </td>
                <td>{oneForm.ref} </td>
                <td> {oneForm.entity}</td>
                <td>{oneForm.customer} </td>

                <td>{oneForm.status} </td>
                <td>
                  <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY" date={oneForm.createdAt} />
                </td>
                <td>
                  <FiEdit3 />
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
      </tbody>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you're asking. Is the UI the same for the `<AllForms />`, `<ValidateOffers />` and `<Ascend />` components?

Comment: Make sure to read the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). Your hooks are not valid although they might be working.

Comment: <AllForms/> <ValidateOffers /> and <Ascend /> have the same UI, i have copy/pase but just changing the map

Comment: @Chris i think you said that because of my isChecked state (i've delete it bc it's not important for this question). I know it's not correct to useState in loop but i'm still searching another way to not do it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a single component for the rendering of the offer rows. The data can be filtered using a single hook that also selects the active filter. You can also pass this down as an argument.

Custom hooks **MUST** start with the `use` keyword. See the Rules of Hooks documentation for more information.

```
const useFilteredOffers = () => {
  const activeFilter = useSelector((state) => state.buttonReducer);
  const offers = useSelector((state) => state.offersReducer);

  return useMemo(() => {
    switch (activeFilter) {
      case 'Ascend': // fix casing
        return offers?.sort((a, b) => b.createdAt.localeCompare(a.createdAt));
      case 'validate':
        return offers?.filter(oneOffer => oneOffer.status == 'validate');
      default:
        return offers;
    }
  }, [activeFilter, offers]);
}

export const OfferList = () => {
  const filteredOffers = useFilteredOffers();

  return (
    <Table hover responsive="md" className="folder__table">
      <thead className="folder__content">
        <tr className="folder__titles">
          <th className="folder__title"> </th>
          <th className="folder__title">Order REF</th>
          <th
            className="folder__title"
          >
            Entité
          </th>
          <th className="folder__title">Customer</th>
          <th className="folder__title">Status</th>
          <th className="folder__title">Date</th>
          <th className="folder__title "> </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <OfferRows offers={filteredOffers} />
    </Table>
  );
};
```

For completeness, here is the OfferRows component.

PS: You won't need to use the `isEmpty` validator because `Array#map` won't have any effect when the Array is empty.

```
export const OfferRows = (offers) => {
  return (
    <>
      <tbody>
      {offers?.map((oneForm) => {
          return (
            <tr key={oneForm.id}>
              <td>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                />
              </td>
              <td>{oneForm.ref} </td>
              <td> {oneForm.entity}</td>
              <td>{oneForm.customer} </td>

              <td>{oneForm.status} </td>
              <td>
                <Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY" date={oneForm.createdAt} />
              </td>
              <td>
                <FiEdit3 />
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I've never done a custom hook but i will check , learn and try this. Thank you :)

Comment: `SelectOffersValidate` is actually a custom hook :-)

Comment: Oh ok i didn't know it was called like this :')